# Increasing graphics detail through script in Mathematica

Tags: image-processing, graphics, wolfram-mathematica

My goal is to generate big graphs and save images of them (PNG, preferably) through a script (that is: without having to interact with them through a notebook).

Example: I generate a complete graph on 100 notes in a Mathematica notebook and saved the graphic. Out comes the wonderfully detailed image below:

[image: Yay! High quality graph:]

But when I save it via script as below:

```
graph = CompleteGraph[100];
Export["mysuperawesomegraph.png", ImageResize[graph, 1000]];
```

[image: I lose all detail in the edges]

Oh no! So much quality is lost! You can't even see the edges anymore...

I've tried changing the number 1000 to numbers up to 15000 in the line:

```
Export["mysuperawesomegraph.png", ImageResize[graph, 1000]];
```

The result seems to be that a bigger image is saved, but with the same level of detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first want to find the good size on screen. This looks good: `Show[graph, ImageSize -> 1000]`

Then export specifying a proper image resolution:

```
Export["mysuperawesomegraph.png", 
       Show[graph, ImageSize -> 1000], ImageResolution -> 200]
```

For more details, check out [this question on mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/296/how-to-export-large-graphics)

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you! For me, setting ImageResolution wasn't necessary - it seems to work without it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Export["mysuperawesomegraph.png", CompleteGraph[100, ImageSize -> 1000]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! It works when using the CompleteGraph[] function, but doesn't generalize to displaying an arbitrary graph in a large image.